# Is it bad practices for uploading Pages and Documents into a single library?

Tags: document-library, wiki-pages, enterprise-wiki

Ever since starting SharePoint I have come to the understanding that website pages (.aspx) are supposed to be kept in Wiki/ Page's libraries, and documents (.docx, .xlsx etc..) are supposed to be stored in Document libraries.

However, I have recently met conditions which require users to upload Documents and Pages into a single library. To achieve this, I was thinking of creating a single Pages library and getting users to upload/ create all content in there.

Would there be any potential issues with this setup choice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing your particular circumstances, I would venture the opinion that it is bad practise.  I'll just make one point - [information management/content management](http://kimfrehe.com/category/sharepoint/), call it what you will.  It is likely at some stage your company will want to implement some form of document lifecycle policy - it is much easier to manage content if it is split in to document libraries, instead of being a 'mix of apples and pears'.

Unless you use the approach of setting information management policies at the site level, setting rules on content type, rather than document libraries.  I've done the latter, due to 'system legacy reasons' and also because my grasp of content types is not yet good enough (I lack the proper education on best practise content type management) - though someone else on this site could point you in the right direction.

[This post](https://sharepointmaven.com/set-retention-deletion-policies-files-folders-sharepoint/), by the SP Maven, is also useful for information management.