# sharepoint sub-library

Tags: migration, move, subfolders

I want to reorganize a project sharepoint with about 10 different libraries, which they have created for each topic. So the plan is, to create one library 'old_project', and move the existing libraries there. So I can create one new one 'project_new' with a better structure and subfolders instead of more than one library. Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not best practise to make loads of folders and sub-folders.  Consider other ways of structuring your documents.  You mention '10 different project libraries' - what's wrong with this structure?  It's easier to customise the security, since perhaps different project groups / departments need different permissions for each project?

Using multiple document libraries allows you to:

- create columns (fields which might apply to one project, but might be meaningless to another project).
- customise security; think 'who needs contribute permissions (read/write), who needs 'read only'?

Check out an [answer I gave to another question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/240813/is-it-bad-practices-for-uploading-pages-and-documents-into-a-single-library/240830#240830), there is a link to a blog in the my answer which I think you'd benefit from reading.

### Updated

In response to your comment; if you want to move a lot of these documents in to a new Document Library create a new column called `Archive` - with the options of Yes/No.  Use this new column to tag documents with a `Yes` if they are old documents.  Then configure a view to either include or exclude any files where the `Archive` column is equal to Yes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and explanation Tally, makes a lot of sense. But is there a way to put all of the old libraries in one folder/library? It is a restart of an old project, so we want to keep the old files but clean up and kind of archive it. Would be nice not to see all of the old libraries in the left 'column' in sharepoint online.

Comment: as for actually moving the files, you can either download them and reupload (slow) or you can use 'Open With Explorer' from the Document Library 'ribbon'.  Get two sessions of Explorer open, once window will be your source Document Library and the other will be your destination.  You can either cut+paste or copy+paste to move the files.  I believe I'm correct in saying cut+paste will preserve the version history (if you are using version history).  If you copy+paste the files will copy over as version 1.0